My front shifter does not shift into the largest chainring
I have a second hand Globe Vienna 03. For some months, switching gears has been working fine. After some time however, the switching of the front gears started to deteriorate. Specifically, the bike would start to have trouble when switching to the highest front gear (biggest chainring). Then, the shifter started to kind of miss the highest front gear. What I mean by this is that, being in the second gear, the lever to switch up to the third front gear would be loose. Pressing it would have no effect whatsoever on the front derailleur.
This was something that would come and go for a week or two, but now it seems to be almost permanent. I have tried adjusting the cable tension with the barrel adjuster, with no apparent effect either by tightening or by loosening the cable. I have also tried increasing the mobility of the derailleur by unscrewing the H limit screw, again with no apparent effect.
Does anybody know what could be causing the problem?
I am going to link one post in the forum that looks like a similar problem, but I am not sure whether it's actually related because the person in that post talks about the rear derailleur too, which isn't part of the problem at all in my case.
Thank you in advance to everyone for reading the post!

Generally speaking, switching gears at the rear is much more frequent than chainring changes.  I only change chainring when approaching a decent climb or a stiff headwind.   If you set your bike up hanging off the ground, hand-pedal and shift with the other hand, does it work better?  Being closer you might be able to see more compared to riding.    Second, while hand-pedalling can you manipuilate the front derailleur to change to the big ring?   Do be mindful of your fingers, there's lots of chompy spaces here.

Mechanical/cable shifting needs periodic maintenance.

Initially, it sounds like the grease in your shifters is starting to gum up/get sticky, which happens over time. This can cause the pawls in the shifter mechanism to not snap cleanly into the next notch, preventing the shifter from pulling the cable.

The fix: The quick fix is to spray in a bicycle-specific solvent to soften the sticky grease and restore the "snap" in the pawls. Some of these products also contain a light lubricant that remains, keeping the system moving freely (until a future repeat of the above is needed). If the solvent does not contain a residual lubricant, then you would need to follow with a light lubricant, again specific to bicycle components.
A more challenging approach would be to disassemble the shifters, but be wary, as some shifting mechanisms are really best left not disassembled.

Another possible factor can be cable wear and/or cable sheath wear. This can create additional friction in the cabling system that will inhibit the free movement of the cable.

The fix: Diagnosing and likely replacing the cable(s) and possibly the cable housing. Squirting some cable lubrication into the sheath and allowing some shifting to work it in can buy some time here.

Finally, cables can fray, typically at locations with higher friction (where cables turn tight bends).

The fix: The obvious fix here is replacing the cable(s), the sooner the better. The problem is not going to get better, and if the cable breaks, you will be stranded in the smallest chainring on the front (or in the case of a rear shifter, the smallest cog on the rear). Also, cable strands can be introduced to your shifter ratchet if the fray is close to the shifter (notorious for current drop bar shifting mechanisms).
